# How can i fix this call back error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rocket.chat

At first, I installed this library,

```
> npm install rocketchat-api
```

and then I've ran this code to use rocket.chat REST API

```
// Node.js code
const RocketChatApi = require('rocketchat-api');
const result='https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/users/setavatar';
const userId='A user id';
const avatarUrl='http://www.coca.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/flowers-love-profile-pictures-1.jpg'
const rocketChatClient = new RocketChatApi(
  'https',
  'rocket.chat',
  443,
  'username',
  'password',
  (err, result)=>{
    console.info('RC connected', result)
});
rocketChatClient.users.setAvatar(userId, avatarUrl, (err, body)=>{
});
```

After run this in Node.js, I got following error, anyone can help me?

```
\node_modules\rocketchat-api\lib\net.js:144
                    return callback ? callback(error, null) : reject(error);
                                      ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Request.clientRequest [as _callback] (D:\node js projects\rocketTest\node_modules\rocketchat-api\lib\net.js:144:39)
    at self.callback (D:\node js projects\rocketTest\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\node js projects\rocketTest\node_modules\request\request.js:819:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:662:40)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Comment: which line triggers the error?

Comment: @alfasin i think this line rocketChatClient.users.setAvatar(userId, avatarUrl, (err, body)=>{
});       ---- in out pout i get a json format information about user, like userID and token and under this json out put i got those error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `setAvatar()` only accepts 2 parameters: `avatarUrl` and `callback`. If you pass 3 parameters, it would take the second one as `callback`, and throw `TypeError` if it is not a function (In your example, the 2nd parameter `avatarUrl` is a string).

Please refer to the source code of `lib/api/users.js` in rocketchat-api [source code](https://github.com/gusnips/rocketchat-api-node/blob/master/lib/api/users.js):

```
setAvatar (avatarUrl, callback) {
    return this.client.request("POST", "users.setAvatar", {
        avatarUrl
    }, callback);
}
```

Unfortunately, the rocketchat-api module's [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rocketchat-api#Users.setAvatar) is incorrect, which leads the problem.